# The function has return type of 'FutureOr<User>', but doesn't end with a return statement

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

[image: snapshot of Firebase Authentication code snipppets]

I am trying to create a repository for use cases of FirebaseAuth and can see warnings!
Should I ignore the warning, as it not impacting the app?
OR should I handle it now, and How?

Comment: Your problem is that if an exception happen, you are just printing the error and ends up returning nothing. You should either rethrow the exception (or a new exception) or return null in the exception handling and indicate in your API that this method can return null.

Comment: return something in the catch block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dart has analyzed your program and found out that you have not handled all cases how the method can exit. This is a potentially a problem since your method signature specifies that you method are returning a `Future<User>` object.

In your case you have not handled the case where an exception are throw from the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method. If an exception are catch, you ends up with a execution path without any `return` statement.

In this case, Dart will at runtime just return `null` so it is not an error. But it is a potential sign of a code error since it it not unlikely that you have forgotten the handling of the exception by not have any `return` statement.

If it is your intention to just return `null` in case of an exception, you should therefore have insert `return null;` in both of your `catch` blocks (or just at the bottom of your method outside the catch-blocks).

Alternative, you can `rethrow` the exception if you just want to add some logging but still let the caller to also handle the exception. You can read more about this in the language tour: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#catch

In either cases, you should describe the behavior in the documentation of the method.